# NSIS start application on Windows startup (without Startup folder)

Tags: startup, nsis

Is it possible to add the application in the install process to some registry, in order for it to start automatically on Windows startup without adding a shortcut to the Startup folder?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can add a entry to the [Run key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/setupapi/run-and-runonce-registry-keys) in the registry:

```
WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" "MyAppName" '"$InstDir\MyApp.exe"'
```

Note: Windows Task Manager has a tab to disable startup items so adding it to the registry instead of the startup folder no longer "hides it" from the user.

Comment: But can it be a .jar extension that i add?

Comment: @R.Ro No, it should point to a .exe. If you don't have one you can create one with one of the free Java launchers. On my machine .jar files just open in 7-zip if you execute them...